# How do you insert multiple lines to a webpage using the span element?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a game that uses a map (of course, this is multiple lines).
I was wondering if you can make the span tag cover multiple lines (with
the end of the row being a new line).

Example map:
-  -  O
-  X O
O - O

Is there any way to get the map to appear exactly how it is above in the webpage?

Here is some code from the JS file:

```
for (var col = 0; col < mapHeight; col++)
{
    for (var row = 0; row < mapWidth; row++)
    {
        var character = map2[col][row];

        if (character == "X" || character == "O")
        {
            alertMessage += " " + character;
        }
        else
        {
            alertMessage += "  " + character;
        }

        document.getElementById("map").innerHTML += character;
    }
    alertMessage += "\n";
    // document.getElementById("map").innerHTML += "\n";
}
```

The last line that is commented out is what I want to do, but it won't work with a simple "\n"

Comment: Whats your current HTML + CSS?

Comment: `<span>`s  are inline. You need something block to break a line. So `<br />`, or wrap you `<span>`s in `<div>`s

Comment: wrap each character / apply css ...not complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your javascript you may have

var map = "-  -  O\n-  X O\nO - O";

Maybe this will come from the server.

You can add lines by doing a

```
map = map.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
```

to add the lines

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a map that is changed by the user, and it is displayed to the user using an alert for now. I wanted to change the alert into an actual element on the page.

Comment: Should be something like document.getElementById('map').innerHTML = map.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");  Or use jquery if you have it

Comment: Thanks, guys - it wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but it definitely helped my solve my problem. I figured it out with document.getElementById("map").innerHTML += "<br />";

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<br>` tag which signifies a line break

```html
<span>--o<br>-xo<br>o-o</span>
```

or the `<pre>` tag which signifies pre-formatted text

```html
<pre>--o
-xo
o-o</pre>
```

or the `<div>` tag which signifies a division of the vertical page flow.

```html
<div>--o</div>
<div>-xo</div>
<div>o-o</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a `pre`.  These preserve whitespace and are generally displayed in a monospace font.

Answer (score 0):

1.
use `<pre>`

2.
use `<br />`

3.
Every line in `<div></div>`
Example:

```
<div><span>-</span><span>-</span><span>o</span></div>
<div><span>-</span><span>x</span><span>o</span></div>
<div><span>o</span><span>-</span><span>o</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<br>` tag within the `<span>` tag.

```
<span>
    - - O<br>
    - X O<br>
    O - O
</span>
```

Here is a jsfiddle to take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/8gtv3wdL/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Thanks everyone for your help!

I did it with this:

document.getElementById("map").innerHTML += "< br />";